# reset select dropdown option when there is no selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reset the select dropdown option when none of the option is selected (set as default the first option of the select dropdown option, when lost the focus on select but no option is selected), as you can see below in my snippet it was able to reset but the problem is, it won't reset when you select an option from the select dropdown option and then click the select again and lost the focus from the select. Any ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations, help please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //restore the first option of the select dropdown option
    var tt = "";
    $(document).on("focus","select",function(){
        $(this).find('option:first-child').prop({ disabled : true }).show();
        tt = $(this).val();
    });
    $(document).on("change","select",function(){
        tt = "";
        $(this).focusout();
    });

    $(document).on("focusout","select",function(){
        if($(this).val() === tt){
           $(this).find('option:first-child').prop({ selected : true, disabled : true }).closest("select").trigger("change");
        }
        tt = "";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select test</option>
  <option value="1">test option 1</option>
  <option value="2">test option 2</option>
  <option value="3">test option 3</option>
  <option value="4">test option 4</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option disabled>Select test</option>
  <option value="1">test option 1</option>
  <option value="2">test option 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>test option 3</option>
  <option value="4">test option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did not understand your question could you please elaborate  more

Comment: run my snippet! first, what i want is if there's none of the option is selected when the select dropdown is on focus then reset the select dropdown by making the first option as a default option (selected is true for the first option), now the problem is when you select on the option and then focus on the select again and then lost the focus on the currently focused select, the select does not reset, you have to select an option and then focus and lost the focus of the select and then focus and lost the focus of the select for the second time to reset the select dropdown which I dont want.

Comment: When you select an option an click the select again, the select doesnt lose it's focus it just closes the dropdown. After jou click something else, then it looses it's focus. Because no changes were made, it resets.

Comment: @Nomeaning25: yeah, try to select on the option and then click anywhere (not on the current focus select) and then click on the select again and click again anywhere, the select will reset. I guess the problem was when the select is on focus, the select wont reset.

Comment: that is correct. You call reset event on `focusout` which happens ony after you click away. You could also listen to click events and check if dropdown is open.

Comment: @Nomeaning25: you can see in my on change event on the select, there is '$(this).focusout();' but I guess it does not work, any ideas please?

Comment: @CodeDemon instead of focusout call `$(this).blur()`

Comment: that solved my issue, thank you! :) @Nomeaning25

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //restore the first option of the select dropdown option
    var tt = "";
    var open = false;
    $(document).on("focus","select",function(){
        if(open) {
            open = false;
        }
        $(this).find('option:first-child').prop({ disabled : true }).show();
        tt = $(this).val();
    });
    $(document).on("change","select",function(){
        tt = "";
        $(this).blur();
    });

    $(document).on("blur","select",function(){
        if($(this).val() === tt){
           $(this).find('option:first-child').prop({ selected : true, disabled : true }).closest("select").trigger("change");
        }
        tt = "";
    });
    //When the dropdown closes it blures the select. Catuion this will also trigger 
    //if you open select and select nothing and close it back. In that case the select 
    //will be reset.
     $(document).on("click","select",function(){
        open = !open;       
        if(!open){
             $(this).blur();
        }
     });
});
```